# ASP.NET MVC 4 Map Route URlL is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have following rout map.

```
  routes.MapRoute(null, "{id}/{rent}/{unit}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Default" });         
  routes.MapRoute(null, "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

  routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", //// Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{rent}/{unit}", //// URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
          new string[] { "CDCPortal" });

  routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultRent", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Default",  id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "CDCPortal" });
```

and Below URLs are working fine.

> localhost/118939/
>
> localhost/118939/120/rent
>
> localhost/Home/Default/118939/120/rent

but

> localhost/Home/Default/118939

is not working properly. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

What if you get rid of `id = UrlParameter.Optional`:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", //// Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{rent}/{unit}", //// URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Default" }, 
          new string[] { "CDCPortal" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `DefaultRent` before `Default` route